# Menu keeps being "clicked". Hover effect goes wrong

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design, hover

I am writing a responsive website. The menu I have has a hover effect (when you hover over it with your mouse, it lights up). The problem is that the clicked menu items will keep being lit up, after you clicked on them.

Example: 
You load the page the first time. Everything is okay. You click on "About". About lights up and you get to about.html (currently still the old page). You return to the index page. About in the menu is still lit up, even though it should not be. Why is that so?

I have the page already online, for testing. Click here: 
http://www.s4ea.org/new/index.html

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/index.htm" target="_blank">Home&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/about.htm"  target="_blank">About Us&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></li>
        <li class="sports"><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/sports.htm"  target="_blank">Sports&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/news.htm" target="_blank" >News & Events&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></li>
        <li class="vols"><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/volunteer.htm" target="_blank" >Volunteer&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></li>
        <li class="donate"><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/donations.htm" target="_blank" >Donate&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/paypal.htm">Donate using PayPal</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/checks.htm">Donate using Check</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/car.htm">Donate Your Car</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/unitedway.htm">United Way Gift</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/goodsearch.htm">Donate using GoodSearch</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/sponsors.htm">Our Sponsors</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/sponsorship.htm">Sponsorship</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/Inkind.htm">Inkind Needs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="http://www.s4ea.org/contact.htm" target="_blank">Contact Us&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></li>  
        <li class="events"><a href="#events" >Upcoming Events&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></li>
        <li class="camps"><a href="#camp" >SPORTS Camps&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></li>  
        <li class="fundraisers"><a href="#fundraisers" >Fundraisers&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></li>     
        </ul>
     </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
.mainheader nav {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height:10%;

}

.mainheader nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0%;
    background-color: #FFF;

}

.mainheader nav ul li {
    float:left;
    display: inline;
    width:14.28%;
    padding: 0% ;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}


.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited {
    color:#FFF;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: 0 auto;
    /*padding:10px 25px 10px 25px;*/
    padding:17.5px 0px 17.5px 0px;
    height: 40px;
} 


/* war hier .mainheader nav a:hover,  .mainheader nav a:active, */
 .mainheader nav .home a:link, .mainheader nav .home a:visited {
    background-color:#ffcc00; /*Farbe nicht Hover */
    text-shadow: none;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}

 .mainheader nav .home a:visited, .mainheader nav .home a:hover {
     background-color:#ffe66a; /*Farbe Hover */
     overflow:hidden;
}

.mainheader nav .about a:link, .mainheader nav .about a:visited {
    background-color:#7ab503; /*Farbe nicht Hover */
    text-shadow: none;

}

 .mainheader nav .about a:visited, .mainheader nav .about a:hover {
     background-color:#bffc43; /*Farbe Hover */

 }

 .mainheader nav .sports a:link, .mainheader nav .sports a:visited {
    background-color:#e47412; /*Farbe nicht Hover */
    text-shadow: none;

}

 .mainheader nav .sports a:visited, .mainheader nav .sports a:hover {
     background-color: #f3a157; /*Farbe Hover */

 }

.mainheader nav .news a:link, .mainheader nav .news a:visited {
    background-color:#00a3d1; /*Farbe nicht Hover */
    text-shadow: none;

}

 .mainheader nav .news a:visited, .mainheader nav .news a:hover {
    background-color: #6cdfff; /*Farbe hover*/
    text-shadow: none;

}

.mainheader nav .vols a:link, .mainheader nav .vols a:visited {
    background-color:#eb10cf; /*Farbe nicht Hover */
    text-shadow: none;

}

 .mainheader nav .vols a:visited, .mainheader nav .vols a:hover{
    background-color: #fb6ce9; /*Farbe hover*/
    text-shadow: none;

}

 .mainheader nav .donate a:link, .mainheader nav .donate a:visited {
    background-color:#e82d24; /*Farbe nicht Hover */
    text-shadow: none;

}

 .mainheader nav .donate a:visited, .mainheader nav .donate a:hover {
     background-color:#f28b86; /*Farbe Hover */
     text-shadow:none;
}

.mainheader nav .donate ul {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    overflow:visible;
}

 .mainheader nav .donate ul li {
     clear: both;
     overflow:visible;
     width: 100%;
}
/* clear: both; Bei der Verwendung dieses Befehls: Ist untereinander, aber es gibt einen Fehler.
*/

 .mainheader nav .donate ul li a {
     height:15px;
}

 .mainheader nav .donate:hover ul {
    display: block;
    background-color: #e82d24;
}

 .mainheader nav .donate:hover ul li:hover {
     background-color:#f28b86;
}

  .mainheader nav .contact a:link, .mainheader nav .contact a:visited {
    background-color:#7cb703; /*Farbe nicht Hover */
    text-shadow: none;

}

 .mainheader nav .contact a:visited, .mainheader nav .contact a:hover {
     background-color:#bffd43; /*Farbe Hover */
     text-shadow:none;
}

 .mainheader nav .events a:link, .mainheader nav .events a:visited {
    background-color:#eb10cf; /*Farbe nicht Hover */
    text-shadow: none;
    display:none;

}

 .mainheader nav .events a:visited, .mainheader nav .events a:hover {
     background-color:#6cdfff; /*Farbe Hover */
     text-shadow:none;
     display:none;

}

  .mainheader nav .camps a:link, .mainheader nav .camps a:visited {
    background-color:#ffcc00; /*Farbe nicht Hover */
    text-shadow: none;
    display:none;

}

 .mainheader nav .camps a:visited, .mainheader nav .camps a:hover {
     background-color:#ffe66a; /*Farbe Hover */
     text-shadow:none;
     display:none;

 }

 .mainheader nav .fundraisers a:link, .mainheader nav .fundraisers a:visited {
    background-color:#00a3d1; /*Farbe nicht Hover */
    text-shadow: none;
    display:none;

}

 .mainheader nav .fundraisers a:visited, .mainheader nav .fundraisers a:hover {
     background-color:#6cdfff; /*Farbe Hover */
     text-shadow:none;
     display:none;

}
```

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I know the page is really not perfect, it is just a test right now and I know the menu is far from professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the same background colour for the link's `:hover` and `:visited` events. So after you've clicked the link, it will stay the same colour as when it was hovered.

Remove the `a:visited` from the CSS selectors and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in one of the a:visited sections in the css. It is setting the color the same as a:hover, so after you click on the link its being marked as visited and will stay that color. If you test on a incognito mode browser that doesn't store visited, then the links don't stay the same color. I'll look through and see if I can find which one is doing it.